# Iteration Level Permission

Tags: tfs, permissions, iteration, scrum

Is it possible to lock down the ability to assign the iteration to myself or a BA role?  My product owner wants to be able to do that.  I do not believe he should have ability to move work items from sprint to sprint. He can change backlog priority but he should be removed from the option of assigning iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A core Scrum and agile philosophy is to support communication over contract negotiation.  By putting in processes within tools such as TFS really goes against the spirit of Scrum and reeks of micro-management.  I would not not recommend going down this path.

However,  if you insist on doing this you can edit the work item template and change the rules on the field to.

```
<READONLY for="TFS role or Domain Group" />
```

Note it only supports TFS groups and domain groups and you cannot restrict it to a user.